# How Equal ComboBox Items to Array Items

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

In Visual Studio I have one `ComboBox` where I enter five items manually. (products) Also `TextBox` where I must write automatically the prices.

In array I save prices of these products and names:

```
string [] prodmas = new string[5];
prodmas[0] = "თევზი";
prodmas[1] = "პური";
prodmas[2] = "ყავა";
prodmas[3] = "შაქარი";
prodmas[4] = "წვენი";

double[] fasmas = new double[5];
fasmas[0] = 1.2;
fasmas[1] = 2;
fasmas[2] = 2.4;
fasmas[3] = 1.3;
fasmas[4] = 2.5;
```

How to do when I select item 1 in `ComboBox`, `TextBox` must show the item 1 price (1.2); when I select item3 `TextBox` must show the item 3 price (2.4)

```
private void produqcia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .......
}

  FULL CODE


  string [] prodmas = new string[5];
        double[] fasmas = new double[5];


        void masivebi()
        {
            prodmas[0] = "თევზი";
            prodmas[1] = "პური";
            prodmas[2] = "ყავა";
            prodmas[3] = "შაქარი";
            prodmas[4] = "წვენი";

            fasmas[0] = 1.2;
            fasmas[1] = 2;
            fasmas[2] = 2.4;
            fasmas[3] = 1.3;
            fasmas[4] = 2.5;

        }




        private void produqcia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int index = produqcia.SelectedIndex;
            fasi.Text = String.Format("The item {0} price {1}", index + 1, fasmas[index].ToString());
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            produqcia.DataSource = prodmas;
        }


    }
```

Comment: you can do this by using `IndexOf` or get the `ItemIndex` in combobox 1 which would be `ItemIndex of 0` also there are a ton of working examples online to do what you are trying to do..

Comment: Why couldn't you just use the Index to match them?

Comment: Add `masivebi();` in `Form1_Load` before `produqcia.DataSource = prodmas;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form constructor or elsewhere:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = prodmas;
```

Selection event:

```
private void produqcia_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    textBox1.Text = String.Format("The item {0} price {1}", index + 1, fasmas[index].ToString());
}
```

But this is not really good approach, better create object holding two of your values and bind it to combobox. Then cast selected item to your object and get needed value.

Comment: when i add this >> comboBox1.DataSource = prodmas;  combobox is clear. it deleted items.